# Alamofire - pass string array as parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire

I'm using swift3, and Alamofire 4.

I need to pass data to an API, the API takes array of strings as POST parameter.

The problem is - as I understand - that Alamofire accepts parameters of type [String: Any] only.

How can I use that API?

**CODE:**

```
func PostAPIWithHeaders(url: String, parameters: [String], header: HTTPHeaders, callback: @escaping (JSON) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
                callback(json)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

This code produce the error: `Extra argument 'method' in call`

And when I change the parameter type from `[String]` to `[String:Any]` it works. But in my case I need to pass [String]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example (best would be a Playground code snippet). Add Screenshots if necessary. And please add the important error message. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: please read the documentation of alamofire, this is well explained here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: and there are many tutorials available

Comment: @muescha Thank you, I already took a look at the documentation and tutorial but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-url-encoded-parameters

Comment: json encoding https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#json-encoding

Comment: make a working test code - then come back and explain your errors showing up

Comment: please full code. the full alamofire call! and how all needed variables are build. we are here to help to find bugs and not to guess your code!

Comment: please read all links in my welcome text. thx

Comment: @muescha I think you didn't understand the problem, please check the update

Comment: i have seen your update - but i can and will not help you without code

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @muescha thank you, please check the code

Comment: how are the requirements of your post endpoint? what is in [String]?

Comment: `Paramters` is a dictionary. of [String:Any} that means at key you should take your parameter from the endpoint. example: `let postParameters: Parameters = [ "lastname": parameters[0]! ]` when the first item is a name.

Comment: each post endpoint need a `key=value` post parameter

Comment: @muescha Yes you are right. But the post endpoint requires array of string, not dictionary.

Comment: how is the exact definition? but the endpoint ned to have an name?

Answer (score 0):

solution is:

```
func PostAPIWithHeaders(url: String, parameters: [String], header: HTTPHeaders, callback: @escaping (JSON) -> ()) {


    let postParameters: Parameters = [ "entpointkeyname": parameters ]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: postParameters, headers: header).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            callback(json)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

PS: it is this line in the alamofire example:

```
"baz": ["a", 1],
```

see: possible json structures: http://json.org/